# Accessing a class variable from different a class

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, scope

A very common, generic question but it seems that everybody has it's own opinion about accessing variables that belong in another class. What I want is to use boolean variable in class2 to perform a statement. Example of what I want is:

```
Class1.h
@Interface Class1{
     bool boolean;
}

@Property (nonatomic, retain) bool boolean;

Class1.m
@synthesize boolean;


Class2.m
if(class1.boolean == YES){
Do Something
}
```

The if statement is class2 doesn't seem to work, as I tried to print the boolean value in class2 and all it returns is false. I want to get the current value of class1 boolean variable and use it in class 2 without initialising it.

Comment: Your question is confusing.  Show the rest of the code around `NSLog()` as "is null" doesn't mean very much to me at the moment.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Can you please post a, minimal, code example illustrating the problem you're facing or the part that is unclear to you? Finally, what makes you think that _"everybody has it's own opinion about accessing variables that belong in another class"_ ?

Comment: To output the BOOL try `NSLog(@"Boolean Value is: %d", (int)self.boolean);`

Comment: sorry if I was unclear I updated the whole question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your question, it seems you want to create an instance of '`Class1`' in another class, get the properties value to be presented there.

In that case, whenever you instantiate '`Class1`', it comes with the initial values. That means the values will be '`null`' for sure. If you want to get the changed value, you need to create '`Class1`' as Singleton class, where, this class will be instantiated once in the whole application. Means change the value of '`boolean1`' in any class, and get the same value in another, whenever or wherever you want.

But again, it totally depends on how you want to use the whole thing.

Singleton example:

```
// Class1.h
@interface Class1 : NSObject

/**
 *  A boolean property
 */
@property (nonatomic, strong) BOOL *boolean;


// Class1.m
@implementation Class1

// This is actual initialisation of the class instance.
+ (Class1 *)sharedInstance {
    static Class1 *sharedInstance = nil; //static property, so that it can hold the changed value
    // Check if the class instance is nil.
    if (!sharedInstance) {
        static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
        dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
            // If nil, create the instance, using dispatch_once, so that this instance never be created again. So, if needed, app will use the existing instance.
            sharedInstance = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
            // custom initialisation if needed

        });
    }
    return sharedInstance;
}

// So that, if somebody uses alloc and init, a new instance not created always.
// Rather use existing instance
+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    return [self sharedInstance];
}

// So that, if somebody uses alloc and init, a new instance not created always.
// Rather use existing instance
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    return self;
}

@end
```

Now updating and using the value.

```
//Class2.m

#import "Class1.h"

Class1 *myinstance = [[Class1 alloc] init];
myinstance.boolean = YES;
```

Getting the value on another class

```
//Class3.m

#import "Class1.h"

Class1 *myinstance = [[Class1 alloc] init];
if(myinstance.boolean == YES){
    Do Something
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. can you briefly explain me what is happening in Class1.m implementation?

Comment: I am editing my answer with comments. Give me some time pls.

Comment: question, does the class1 has to be of NSObject type?

Comment: It depends, what you want to inherit in the singleton class. But for the basic functionalities 'NSObject' is must. As NSObject is the root class.

Comment: I found out that the best way to do so is by return the variable using a method. That was the only way to access the current value of the variable\